# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm working on a python3 lab that requires me to write a python code that generates datapoints. There also needs to be at least 200 different points for each line. Use sizes like 10000.

However, I keep getting an error stating that "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'float'" caused by the underlined portion of code below. I understand that numpy doesn't work with map() on python3 and that I'll have to change "total_steps" into a list but I haven't been able to find a solution that works.

```
#!/usr/local/python3

import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

def partition(arr, low, high): 
    i = (low-1)   
    pivot = arr[high] 
  
    for j in range(low, high): 
        if arr[j] <= pivot: 
            i = i+1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i] 
  
    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1] 
    return (i+1) 
  
def quickSort(arr, low, high, step): 
    if len(arr) == 1: 
        return step
    if low < high: 
        pi = partition(arr, low, high) 
  
        step += quickSort(arr, low, pi-1, step)
        step += quickSort(arr, pi+1, high, step)
        step += 1
    
    return step

def gen(size):
    return [random.randrange(10000) for i in range(size)]

def to_decimal(l):
    return [Decimal(i) for i in l]


sizes = sorted(random.sample(range(200, 10001), 20))
print(sizes)
total_steps = []
for size in sizes:
    datapoints = gen(size)
    total_steps.append(quickSort(datapoints, 0, size-1, 0))

print(total_steps)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

sizes = np.array(sizes)/10000

total_steps = np.array(map(Decimal,total_steps))*0.00001
--------------------------------------------------------


plt.plot(sizes, to_decimal(total_steps))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn a little more debugging.  Work through your objects:

```
>>> map(Decimal,total_steps)
<map object at 0x0000028E0938D940>
>>> np.array(map(Decimal,total_steps))
array(<map object at 0x0000028E0938D748>, dtype=object)
>>> np.array(list(map(Decimal,total_steps)))
array([Decimal('620'), Decimal('1239'), Decimal('2003'), Decimal('2059'),
       Decimal('2326'), Decimal('2444'), Decimal('2607'), Decimal('4053'),
       Decimal('4093'), Decimal('4275'), Decimal('4364'), Decimal('4873'),
       Decimal('6015'), Decimal('6680'), Decimal('6740'), Decimal('8155'),
       Decimal('8288'), Decimal('8523'), Decimal('9145'), Decimal('9637')],
      dtype=object)
```

You originally made a NumPy array with a single element, a `map` object -- an iterator, not the *result* of the iteration.  To get the result, you need to force the iteration, such as with the `list` constructor.  Even then, you have an array of `Decimal` objects.  You cannot multiply that by a `float`.  You need to convert them to compatible types.  For instance,

```
np.array(list(map(Decimal,total_steps))) * Decimal(0.00001)
```

Comment: Good catch. Missed the Decimal part issue.

Comment: I also missed it at first -- but this is why we have to test our solutions before posting, just as the poster has to test their MRE before submitting.

Answer (score 2):

`map` returns a map object. You are getting this error because you are trying to multiply an array containing a single map object by a float.

You should coerce it to a list so the array is created with a compatible type:

```
total_steps = np.array(list(map(Decimal,total_steps))) * Decimal(0.00001)
```

Alternatively, you can use `np.fromiter`:

```
total_steps = np.fromiter(map(Decimal,total_steps), float) * Decimal(0.00001)
```